Unable to Run Gazebo on WSL 2 with VcXsrv: 'Qt platform plugin xcb' Issues
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL and attempting to install ROS2 Foxy along with Gazebo 11. After installing Gazebo, when I run gazebo --verbose, I encounter the following error:
[Msg] Waiting for master.
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.14.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://
[Msg] Publicized address: 
[Err] [RenderEngine.cc:749] Can't open display: localhost:0.0
[Wrn] [RenderEngine.cc:89] Unable to create X window. Rendering will be disabled
[Wrn] [RenderEngine.cc:292] Cannot initialize render engine since render path type is NONE. Ignore this warning if rendering has been turned off on purpose.
[Msg] Loading world file [/usr/share/gazebo-11/worlds/empty.world]
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://
[Msg] Publicized address: 
[Err] [RenderEngine.cc:749] Can't open display: localhost:0.0
[Wrn] [RenderEngine.cc:89] Unable to create X window. Rendering will be disabled
[Wrn] [RenderEngine.cc:292] Cannot initialize render engine since render path type is NONE. Ignore this warning if rendering has been turned off on purpose.
[Wrn] [GuiIface.cc:114] could not connect to display localhost:0.0
[Msg] Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
[Err] [GuiIface.cc:118] This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.


I have been working on setting up ROS2 Foxy and Gazebo 11 on Ubuntu 20.04 running under WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). Here is a summary of what I have tried:
Reinstalled ROS2 Foxy and Gazebo 11:
I uninstalled ROS2 Foxy and Gazebo 11, then reinstalled them to ensure a clean setup.
Verified WSL Version:
I confirmed that I am using WSL 2, which is required for proper GUI support with Gazebo.
Installed and Configured X Server:
I installed and configured VcXsrv as the X server on Windows.
I ensured that VcXsrv was running and correctly configured with the appropriate settings.
Configured DISPLAY Environment Variable:
I set the DISPLAY environment variable in WSL to localhost:0.0.
Installed Required Qt Packages:
I installed and reinstalled the necessary Qt packages, including libqt5xcbqpa5, libqt5gui5, and libqt5x11extras5.
Checked for X Server and Display Issues:
I verified that VcXsrv was running and accessible.
I ran xclock and encountered the error Error: Can't open display: localhost:0.0, indicating that the X server could not be reached.
Verified Firewall and Network Configuration:
I checked firewall settings to ensure that VcXsrv was allowed through the firewall.
Despite these efforts, I am still encountering issues with launching Gazebo, and the same errors persist. Specifically, I receive an error related to the inability to open the display and the Qt platform plugin xcb.
I may have tried some unnecessary steps, but I have attempted various solutions to resolve this error.
I am expecting guidance on resolving these issues, specifically regarding X server configuration and display connection problems within a WSL environment.

One option that I've seen work in the past(depending on what your /etc/hosts/ looks like) is export DISPLAY=$(hostname):0
